# Android: Trying to add RSA public key to my android apk

Tags: android

I'm trying to add the RA public key that was given to me when I tried to download my apk file.
I got the following directions
1. left click on project name
2. click on export.

There will be a option to include the securty key.

When I did this I only hd 2 options that saod
1. use existing keystore
2. create new keystore.

I don't see anything for including the RA public key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I got really confuse, I thoght the liscence key was suppose to be used to code sgne it.

Comment: Is the RSA public key needed only for paid apps ?